# getting an error of type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have imported the datetime

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime
```

then here i am getting an error

```
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
current_month = datetime.datetime.now().month

current_day = datetime.datetime.now().day
current_week = datetime.date(current_year, current_month, current_day).isocalendar()[1]

min_creation_date_to_be_considered_internal = "2023-03-15"
min_creation_date_to_be_considered_external = "2023-03-28"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTrbH.png)

if i use

```
current_year = datetime.now().year
current_month = datetime.now().month

current_day = datetime.now().day
# current_week = datetime.date(current_year, current_month, current_day).isocalendar()[1]
current_week = datetime.date(current_year, current_month, current_day).isocalendar()[1]
min_creation_date_to_be_considered_internal = "2023-03-15"
min_creation_date_to_be_considered_external = "2023-03-28"
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYSJ6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Rather you change your import to be:

```
import datetime   
...  
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
```

Or you change the method calls:

```
from datetime import datetime  
current_year = datetime.now().year
```

Edit: the second error is due to the incorrect `import`. To fix it:

```
import datetime
current_year = datetime.datetime.now().year
...
current_week = datetime.date(current_year, current_month, current_day).isocalendar()[1]
```

Comment: I am still getting an error i have added the screenshot on the question

Comment: Use `import datetime` with `datetime.datetime.now()` for the first error, then, use datetime.date(...).isocalendar()[1] for the second error.

Answer (score -1):

The reason for the issue is that you are using datetime.datetime, instead you should use datetime only. This is because you have already imported datetime from the datetime module so use it directly. Try this code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from datetime import datetime

current_year = datetime.now().year
current_month = datetime.now().month
current_day = datetime.now().day
current_week = datetime.date(current_year, current_month, current_day).isocalendar()[1]

min_creation_date_to_be_considered_internal = "2023-03-15"
min_creation_date_to_be_considered_external = "2023-03-28"
```

Comment: I am still getting an error i have added the screenshot on the question